# Rendering Selected Food Items ReactJs (Material-UI)

Tags: reactjs, menu, material-ui, cart

I want to render items in a list. When a button is pressed, it adds a food item (drink) to the list named cart. I want to render this list in a material ui dialog when a button is pressed. It is blank. What am I doing wrong?

```
        import { Button, IconButton, List, ListItem, Typography } from "@material-ui/core"
import Order from './Order'
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

import Appbar from '@material-ui/core/Appbar'
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar'

import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions'


import React, {useState} from 'react'
const Menue = () => {
    
    const cart = []
    const [cartOpen, setCartOpen] = useState(false)

    function toggleOrder(){
        alert(cart)
        setCartOpen(! cartOpen)
    }
    function addToCart(e){
        cart.push(e.target.innerText)
        console.log(cart)
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <Typography variant="h2" component="h2" gutterBottom>
                Speisekarte
            </Typography>
            <Typography>Getränke:</Typography>
            <Button name = "milch" onClick = {addToCart}>Milch</Button>
            <Button name = "cola" onClick = {addToCart}>Cola</Button>
            <Button name = "lassi" onClick = {addToCart}>Lassi</Button>
            <Button name = "sprite" onClick = {addToCart}>Sprite</Button>
            <Button onClick = {toggleOrder}>Order</Button>
            <Dialog fullScreen open = {cartOpen} onClose = {toggleOrder}>
                {
                    cart.map(item => {
                        return(
                            <h3>{item}</h3>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Menue
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need to do:

```
const [cart,setCart]=useState([]);
function addToCart(e){
        setCart([...cart,e.target.innerText]);
        
    }
```

You cant manipulate a const variable in react like the way you are trying to do.It's not changing the value of cart,infact after you make a variable const (the way you have done it) you can never manipulate that variable,whatever value you have assigned to it in the beginning will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Cart needs to be a piece of state. Change cart to useState() and change your code accordingly to fit that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `useState` for your cart.

```js
const [cart, setCard] = useState([])
```

and then update your `addToCart` function like so:

```js
function addToCard(e) {
  setCart(cart => [...cart, e.target.innerText])
}
```